# Python code - Combining strings with variables

Tags: python

I Have the code:

```
self.bussTrack = Label(self.frame, text="Buss left:", self.buss, height=1, width=2, font = ("Arial",36))
self.bussTrack.pack()
```

The problem is with the **text="Buss left:", self.buss** bit where I am combining a string and a initialiser variable & python does not allow me to go ahead.

Can somebody help me point the error that print Black

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.bussTrack = Label(self.frame, text="Buss left: %s" % self.buss, height=1, width=2, font = ("Arial",36))
self.bussTrack.pack()
```

You can asign variables to a string with the operator %, %s means is parsed to string

```
In [1]: string = "hello %s" % "world"

In [2]: print string
hello world
```

Comment: I thought about `text="Buss left: " + str(self.buss)`, but yours is better